# How to execute an external .sql file pass-through query in ms-access

Tags: vba, ms-access, pass-through

I have a couple of pass-through queries stored in ms-access that were created via the query design wizard. I simply copied and pasted the code from my local .sql file into the sql view editor in access and saved it. Everything runs fine.

However, I would like to run my external .sql file from access. My external .sql file is located in a local folder. This way, I don't have to  update my external .sql file and my stored query in ms-access when I change something to either query.

For what it's worth, all my pass-through queries are 'SELECT * FROM '

Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: You can use VBA to read the contents of the external .sql file into a `String` and then use that to update the `.SQL` property of the `QueryDef` object for the pass-through query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @GordonThompson advises, simply read the contents of you .sql (which is a text file like any other programming script) into the [.SQL property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/querydef-sql-property-dao) of a [QueryDef](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/querydef-object-dao) (referencing your saved query).

```vb
Sub ReadAndSaveSQL()
    Dim LoadFileStr As String
    Dim qdef As QueryDef  

    ' READ .SQL INTO A STRING VARIABLE
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
          LoadFileStr = .OpenTextFile("C:\Path\To\Script.sql", 1).readall
    End With

    ' INITIALIZE QUERYDEF
    Set qdef = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("mySavedPassThroughQuery")

    qdef.SQL = LoadFileStr                       ' REWRITE QUERY'S SQL
    qdf.Close                                    ' CLOSE AND SAVE QUERY
    Set qdef = Nothing                           ' UNINITIALIZE QUERYDEF

    DoCmd.OpenQuery "mySavedPassThroughQuery"    ' OPEN SELECT QUERY TO SCREEN
End Sub
```

Comment: `qdef.Close` isn't necessary, setting `qdef.SQL` automatically saves it.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks much. Also, my pass through queries begin with some sort of variable declaration such as:

`DECLARE @year As VARCHAR(4);`
`SELECT @year = '2019;'`

Would there be a way to modify the year in the variable ? Perhaps 2018 or 2017 instead of 2019

Comment: Remove those two commands and run a replace on string: `Replace(LoadFileStr, "@year", "'2019'")`. Parameterization is not available with pass-through queries which use DAO. Consider [ADO parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/parameters-collection-ado?view=sql-server-2017) to protect again [malicious user input](https://xkcd.com/327/). However, ADO does not work with QueryDefs.

Comment: Hmmm. I also see that the queryDef is basically just a temporary place to store the string correct ? I can just have one queryDef named "TempQueryDef" and assign a different string to it every time I want to display the query. Is this common practice ?

Comment: You can do that or even create queries with [`CreateQueryDef`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/database-createquerydef-method-dao) from SQL. But need to then assign [connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/querydef-connect-property-dao) details for pass-through. Hence, why it is easier to re-use same pass-through query.